# npm pack taking extremely long

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using npm version 5.6.0 and running
`bash
npm pack -ddd`

where -ddd is the maximum verbosity.  The npm pack takes extremely long (in fact it may be hanging as it seems to be hanging on the prepack phase) when the bundledDependencies include all dependencies.  Obviously there is the tar zip that could be making the packing unreasonably long. Have others had this experience and what was the solution?

output of the command given below.  It just hangs on the last step shown.

`npm pack -ddd
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'pack', '-ddd' ]
npm info using npm@5.6.0
npm info using node@v9.2.0
npm verb npm-session ae9cf4a7728a0813
npm sill pacote directory manifest for undefined@file: fetched in 15ms
npm info lifecycle Bot@1.0.0~prepublish: Bot@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle Bot@1.0.0~prepare: Bot@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle Bot@1.0.0~prepack: Bot@1.0.0
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠏ : info lifecycle Bot@1.0.0~prepack: Bot@1.0.0`

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like a bug in npm.  I downgraded to npm 5.3 as suggested in this post https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19083 and the problem is solved.